# Duda sobre minijuego en C#

Tags: c#, poo

estoy intentando modelar el "Juego de la vida" de John Conway en c#, y básicamente la idea es que el contenido del tablero sea extraído de un archivo txt, mi problema es que al modelar las clases no puedo extrar el contenido del tablero., mis clases son estas(están todas en un .cs diferente, menos la clase tablero y célula, la cuál están en un mismo.cs, Tablero.cs) mi archivo se txt se llama board.txt y según me dice el error cuándo hago el debug, debo tener un problema al intentar extrar el tablero de la (url)

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace PII_Game_Of_Life
{
    public class Logica //cumple con el patrón SRP ya que tiene una única responsabilidad
    {
        public void UpdateBoard(Tablero gameBoard, Tablero cloneboard)
        {
            int boardWidth = gameBoard.GetWidth();
            int boardHeight = gameBoard.GetHeight();
            for (int x = 0; x < boardWidth; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < boardHeight; y++)
                {
                    int aliveNeighbors = 0;
                    for (int i = x - 1; i <= x + 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = y - 1; j <= y + 1; j++)
                        {
                            if (i >= 0 && i < boardWidth && j >= 0 && j < boardHeight && cloneboard.GetCelula(i, j).IsAlive())
                            {
                                aliveNeighbors++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (cloneboard.GetCelula(x, y).IsAlive())
                    {
                        aliveNeighbors--;
                    }
                    if (cloneboard.GetCelula(x, y).IsAlive() && aliveNeighbors < 2)
                    {
                        //Celula muere por baja población
                        cloneboard.SetCelula(x, y, false);
                    }
                    else if (cloneboard.GetCelula(x, y).IsAlive() && aliveNeighbors > 3)
                    {
                        //Celula muere por sobrepoblación
                        cloneboard.SetCelula(x, y, false);
                    }
                    else if (!cloneboard.GetCelula(x, y).IsAlive() && aliveNeighbors == 3)
                    {
                        //Celula nace por reproducción
                        cloneboard.SetCelula(x, y, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Celula mantiene el estado que tenía
                        cloneboard.SetCelula(x, y, gameBoard.GetCelula(x, y).IsAlive());
                    }
                        gameBoard.SetGameBoard(cloneboard.GetGameBoard());
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace PII_Game_Of_Life
{
    public class Tablero 
    {
        private Celula[,] gameBoard;
        private int boardWidth;
        private int boardHeight;
        private Tablero cloneboard;
        private Tablero initialBoard;

        public Tablero(int boardWidth, int boardHeight) 
        {
            this.boardWidth = boardWidth;
            this.boardHeight = boardHeight;
            gameBoard = new Celula[boardWidth, boardHeight];
            for (int i = 0; i < boardWidth; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < boardHeight; j++) 
                {
                    gameBoard[i, j] = new Celula(false);
                }
            }
        }

        public void SetCelula(int x, int y, bool estado) 
        {
            gameBoard[x, y].SetEstado(estado);
        }

        public Celula GetCelula(int x, int y) 
        {
            return gameBoard[x, y];
        }

        public Celula[,] GetGameBoard() 
        {
            return gameBoard;
        }

        public void SetGameBoard(Celula[,] newGameBoard) 
        {
            gameBoard = newGameBoard;
        }

        public int GetLength() 
        {
            return boardWidth * boardHeight;
        }

        public int GetWidth() 
        {
            return boardWidth;
        }

        public int GetHeight() 
        {
            return boardHeight;
        }

        public Tablero GetCloneboard()
        {
            return cloneboard;
        }

        public void SetInitialBoard(Tablero initialBoard) 
        {
            this.initialBoard = initialBoard;
        }
    }

    public class Celula 
    {
        private bool alive;

        public Celula(bool state) 
        {
            alive = state;
        }

        public bool IsAlive() 
        {
            return alive;
        }

        public void SetEstado(bool estado) 
        {
            alive = estado;
        }
    }



}
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace PII_Game_Of_Life
{

    public class Dibujartablero //cumple con el patrón SRP ya que tiene una única responsabilidad
    {
        private int width; // variable que representa el ancho del tablero
        private int height; // variable que representa altura del tablero
        private Tablero initialBoard; // instancia de la clase Tablero

        public Dibujartablero(Tablero tablero)
        {
            this.initialBoard = tablero.GetCloneboard();
            this.width = tablero.GetWidth();
            this.height = tablero.GetHeight();
        }

        public int getDibujarTableroHeight()
        {
            return height;
        }

        public int getDibujarTableroWidth()
        {
            return width;
        }

        public void Dibujar() //cumple con el patrón SRP ya que tiene una única responsabilidad
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (!Console.IsOutputRedirected)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {
                        if (initialBoard.GetCelula(x, y).IsAlive())
                        {
                            s.Append("|X|");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            s.Append("___");
                        }
                    }
                    s.Append("\n");
                }
                Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
                //=================================================
                //Invocar método para calcular siguiente generación
                //=================================================
                Thread.Sleep(300);
                }
            }   
            
        }
    }
}
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using PII_Game_Of_Life;

namespace PII_Game_Of_Life
{


    public class LeerArchivo
    {
        public static Tablero LeerTableroDesdeArchivo(string url)//cumple con el patrón SRP ya que tiene una única responsabilidad
        {
            string content = File.ReadAllText(url);
            string[] contentLines = content.Split('\n');
             Tablero board = new Tablero(contentLines[0].Length, contentLines.Length);
            for (int y = 0; y < contentLines.Length; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < contentLines[y].Length; x++)
                {
                    if (contentLines[y][x] == '1')
                    {
                        board.SetCelula(x,y,true);
                    }
                }
            }
            return board;
        }
    }

}
using System;
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading; 
using System.IO;

namespace PII_Game_Of_Life
{
    class Program
    
    {
        public static void Main(string[]args)
        {   //Leo la ruta que tiene lleva al archivo
            string url="board.txt";
            Tablero tablero=LeerArchivo.LeerTableroDesdeArchivo(url);

            //crear instancia de dibujar tablero
            Dibujartablero dibujarTablero= new Dibujartablero(tablero);

            //imprimir el contenido del tablero
            Console.WriteLine("Tablero inicial: ");
            dibujarTablero.Dibujar();

        }
    

    }
}
```

Comment: De que error hablas (aca no lo mostraste)... luego de ello, tu archivo esta en la misma ruta que tu ejecutable? es posible que este buscando un archivo en otro lugar...

Comment: Tienes razón, perdón, si, mi archivo está en la misma carpeta que mi ejecutable, en este caso los dos están en la carpeta debug, program.cs y board.txt , y el error que me salta es este

Comment: : PS C:\Users\Leo84\Documents\Programación2\Juegodelavida\JuegodelUnhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at PII_Game_Of_Life.Dibujartablero.Dibujar() in C:\Users\Leo84\Documents\Programación2\Juegodelavida\Juegodelavidajoseignlave\src\Library\DibujarTablero.cs:line 43
   at PII_Game_Of_Life.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Leo84\Documents\Programación2\Juegodelavida\Juegodelavidajoseignlave\src\Program\Program.cs:line 21

Comment: Tu error, que deberia estar en la pregunta (usa el boton [edit] y podes editar la publicacion) ya tiene una solucion en el sitio, y solo podes hacerlo vos...

Comment: Hola Jose, me cuesta un poco seguir el hilo de tu programa, me parece que al no instanciar la clase **Logica** no quedan instanciados ni **cloneboard** ni **initialBoard**.